# I am using Expo for building an app in which i am working in OTP authentication

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

// function PhoneSignIn() {
//     // If null, no SMS has been sent
//     const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);

//     const [code, setCode] = useState('');

// Handle the button press


export default class login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            number:''
        }
    }
    signInWithPhoneNumber = async() => {
        const {number} = this.state
        const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        // setConfirm(confirmation);
        console.log("confirmation ==>",confirmation)
        if (confirmation._auth._authResult) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Verify")
        }else {
            alert("internal error")
        }
    }

    // async function confirmCode() {
    //   try {
    //     await confirm.confirm(code);
    //   } catch (error) {
    //     console.log('Invalid code.');
    //   }
    // }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.4, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Login with your number</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 0.4, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <TextInput
                    onChangeText = {(number) => this.setState({number:number})}
                        placeholder={"Please enter your number"}
                        style={{
                            padding: 10,
                            backgroundColor: "#fff",
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            fontSize: 18,
                        }} />
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.signInWithPhoneNumber}
                    style={{
                        padding: 10,
                        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
                        borderRadius: 10
                    }}><Text style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    }}>
                        Send Code</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling f]rebase.app().
- node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\internal\registry\nativeModule.js:227:10 in getAppModule
- node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\internal\registry\app.js:49:23 in initializeNativeApps
- node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\internal\registry\app.js:79:24 in getApp
- node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\internal\registry\namespace.js:136:24 in firebaseModuleWithApp
* LogIn\login.js:23:35 in signInWithPhoneNumber
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:190:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:212:38 in enqueue
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:239:8 in exports.async
* LogIn\login.js:21:28 in signInWithPhoneNumber
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:691:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:628:6 in _receiveSignal
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:524:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:500:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:597:41 in executeDispatch
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:621:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2521:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
* [native code]:null in forEach
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:836:4 in forEachAccumulated
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2546:20 in runEventsInBatch
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2702:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch 
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2639:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0       
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17712:13 in batchedUpdates$1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Share your list packge.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install this library correctly. You didn't configure the firebase correctly. Here is the example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from "react-native";
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

// Initialize Firebase JS SDK
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
try {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyApGoaZVtoVTYnftHSbT9l7nDmDVUYJYpU',
      authDomain: 'playground-d4e7b.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://playground-d4e7b.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'playground-d4e7b',
      storageBucket: 'playground-d4e7b.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '903405300293',
      appId: '1:903405300293:web:c55227a2b8064da05d112c',
  });
} catch (err) {
  // ignore app already initialized error in snack
}

export default function App() {
  const recaptchaVerifier = React.useRef(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = React.useState();
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = React.useState();
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = React.useState();
  const firebaseConfig = firebase.apps.length ? firebase.app().options : undefined;
  const [message, showMessage] = React.useState((!firebaseConfig || Platform.OS === 'web')
    ? { text: "To get started, provide a valid firebase config in App.js and open this snack on an iOS or Android device."}
    : undefined);

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20, marginTop: 50 }}>
      <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
        ref={recaptchaVerifier}
        firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter phone number</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        placeholder="+1 999 999 9999"
        autoFocus
        autoCompleteType="tel"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        textContentType="telephoneNumber"
        onChangeText={(phoneNumber) => setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Send Verification Code"
        disabled={!phoneNumber}
        onPress={async () => {
          // The FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal ref implements the
          // FirebaseAuthApplicationVerifier interface and can be
          // passed directly to `verifyPhoneNumber`.
          try {
            const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber,
              recaptchaVerifier.current
            );
            setVerificationId(verificationId);
            showMessage({
              text: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
            });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter Verification code</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        editable={!!verificationId}
        placeholder="123456"
        onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
      />
      <Button
        title="Confirm Verification Code"
        disabled={!verificationId}
        onPress={async () => {
          try {
            const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId,
              verificationCode
            );
            await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
            showMessage({ text: "Phone authentication successful " });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
          }
        }}
      />
      {message ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { backgroundColor: 0xffffffee, justifyContent: "center" }]}
          onPress={() => showMessage(undefined)}>
          <Text style={{color: message.color || "blue", fontSize: 17, textAlign: "center", margin: 20, }}>
            {message.text}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : undefined}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried your code but this error is coming. I try to solve but it's still showing the same error:

> Unable to resolve module react-native-webview from D:\React Native\SDR-Project\node_modules\expo-firebase-recaptcha\build\WebView.js: react-native-webview could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

[Link to snake.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev/@sid/firebase-phone-auth)

Comment: Unable to resolve module react-native-webview from D:\React Native\SDR-Project\node_modules\expo-firebase-recaptcha\build\WebView.js: react-native-webview could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
> 1 | export { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

Comment: install react-native-webview in your project with commad npm i react-native-webview

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Aftab brother i really appreciate it...... seriously it help me a lot. Thanks again i should have see the documentation first.!!!

Comment: OK, thanks. Note that I did not receive a comment notification - I am only notified if I am the only commenter. Please get into the habit of using `@name` when replying - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the expo docs, there is also a mention of installing react-native-webview

```
npx expo install react-native-webview
```